# How to Force iPad / OneNote re-sync

Tags: ipad

Does anyone know of a solution, from the iPad side of the equation, for this [OneNote syncing problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/onenote-for-ipad3-creating-sync-issues/b8d5c3d2-5018-4cf9-b2b1-402af8fad491?tm=1333232843753)?

Comment: Can you restate the question here in case the link goes stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the iPad's "Settings," there is a OneNote tab which offers a "Reset Application".  Using that seemed to have fixed the problem.